# Full access to a specific folder on Google Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I wonder if there is way to request an end user to allow access to a specific folder on his/her drive? Looking at the scopes: https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes, I do not see a way to achive it.
The end game is to have a folder that both me and the user can collaborate on (and request minimum scope).
Obviously, I can ask full access to the drive and navigate to that folder. I rather not to take this road as it is not aligned with Google’s best practice guide ( requesting minimum scope).

Another option might be using ‘Use Application-owned Accounts’ :https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts. In this scenario, I will ask the user to share a folder with my application. Will that be easier? Do you see any pitfalls going down this road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do so with the current Drive scopes. Using ‘Use Application-owned Accounts’ works (https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts). In this scenario, I will ask the user to share a folder with my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can request permission to a single file but that wont help since you want an arbitrary folder. So its not possible to share a folder.
you could use the appdata folder (https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata) but the user cant see the folder, its hidden.

Service accounts wont help you, it would use its own drive, not the user's.